# Script to add secondary mail accounts

Tags: powershell, scripting, smtp, imap

I would like to realize a PowerShell script which add additional generic IMAP/SMTP mail account(s), ie manually adding credentials, server names, ports, security methods, etc.

Such script should be *"client-agnostic"*, so add the above informations onto MSOutlook or WindowsMail or ThunderBird depending on what desktop client is locally installed.

Currently I haven't found any module/cmdlet yet, but only codes specific for Exchange or MAPI such Gmail.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Please share your piece of effort.

Comment: Here there is a preliminary draft https://github.com/dcorrada/POWERSHELL/blob/tempus/miscellaneous/AddMailAccount.ps1